# W65C02 QFP Package Information

Tags: eaglecad, packages

I am making an Eagle part for the WDC 65C02 part (QFP version).

I can't find any specific package info in the datasheet other than the pinout, and the fact that it's a 44 pin QFC.

My question is, "Are all 44 pin QFC packages the same, and if so, where do I find the specific info I need to make the Eagle footprint?"

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of these answers are not addressing your concern and do not even seem to know what a 65c02 processor is and why you'd still want to use it!  Go figure!  It is still being used and is considered IP.  I asked David Cramer of WDC about this very issue and he told me that they use the JEDEC package dimensions.  I trust them and have ordered parts myself for my designs since they've put this part in this package into their distribution channels.

Answer (score 4):

I contacted the Western Design Center for clarification, and David Cramer, their VP of Business Development, sent me a PDF with the package drawing for the W65C02S6TQG-14 part.  Here are the details you're looking for, transcribed from the PDF:

- 10mm x 10mm body width (that's the plastic package)
- 13.2mm x 13.2mm outline rectangle (out to the tips of the pins, i.e. the pins protrude 1.6mm in each direction)
- 0.8mm pin spacing (from the center of one pin to the center of its neighbor)
- 0.3mm pin width
- 2.7mm max package height

I would check in the standard Eagle libraries to see if there's already a footprint named something like "TQFP-44 10x10mm body 0.8mm spacing".  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not assume all 44 pin quad flatpack are the same.  Many probably are, but the one you rely on may not be.  Surely the mechanical information is available somehow.  You didn't link to the datasheet, so I can't say for sure how to chase this down.  Good datasheets contain the mechanical information.  Some companies (Fairchild comes to mind) use separate datasheets for each package, and refer to the specific package info in the part datasheet.  It's a bit of a hassle to have to find and download the mechanical datasheet separately, but the information is still all there.  At worst, they may reference a JEDEC registered package.  That's more of a hassle to dig up and find, but it's still available.

If the datasheet really doesn't include or reference the mechanical specs somehow (I seriously doubt that), then that should be a warning not to use parts from that company.  You don't say what this WDCxxxx part is and what it does, but surely there is another way to solve your problem by using some alternate part.

As a last resort, contact the manufacturer and request the mechanical information.  But, any company that doesn't make it accessible in the first place probably won't make it easy to talk to someone intelligent either, and then you have to wonder about accuracy of any information they may tell you over the phone.  Unless they can send you a datasheet for the super secret mechanical info, I probably wouldn't believe what they say anyway.  I'd probably use a different part from a different manufacturer before wasting time trying to talk to someone to help me at the first company.

Comment: The datasheet is located at: http://www.westerndesigncenter.com/wdc/documentation/w65c02s.pdf

Comment: I've googled, and searched the datasheet to no avail. Unfortunately, this is the only company that I know of who produces this part. They are very friendly, though, so maybe I'll email them.

Comment: FYI: The part is an 8-bit microprocessor used in many early computers, including the Apple 1 and II. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502

Comment: @Adrian: That looks like more of a synopsis than a real datasheet.  Either you just haven't found the real datasheet yet (likely), or these guys are complete idiots and you should stay away (much less likely).

Comment: @Adrian: What do you need a 6502 microprocessor for anyway?  There are many many modern microcontrollers that can do accomplish anything a 6502 can accomplish.

Comment: You're right. The 6502 is very old. I'm working on an Apple 1 replica for fun.

Comment: If you're working on an Apple I replica you should use DILs, not QFPs!

Comment: *"If the datasheet really doesn't include or reference the mechanical specs"*. It doesn't, but that can easily be explained. It's a 32 page document, and half of it doesn't belong in a datasheet, but in a programming manual (addressing modes, instruction set, opcodes,...). There simply was no more room for what *does* belong in a datasheet.

Comment: @AdrianSarli, the datasheet you link doesn't list QFP as an available package for the part -- why do you think QFP is available? They do list DIP and PLCC options. These packages are much more standard than QFP and you can *very likely* get away with using a standard package for them --- I notice some of their demo boards use the PLCC in a socket, so there's every reason to expect they are not using any customized version of that package.

Comment: @ThePhoton - Does too. The QFP layout is on page 14.

Comment: Table 10, Page 32 lists only two orderable options: 40-pin plastic dual in-line (DIP) and 44-pin plastic leaded chip carrier (PLCC). Why they show a pin-out for a package they don't have as an orderable part number is (not really) difficult to explain.

Comment: @stevenvh - Maybe the term replica isn't correct. I want to build a software-compatible clone, but I want to take advantage of the change in technology between then and now. I'm doing a new board layout, which is why I need the footprint.

Comment: @ThePhoton - You can indeed order a QFP. See http://www.westerndesigncenter.com/wdc/Form_Order_Form.cfm part W65C02S6TQG-14. Also @ Jameco - http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_2143654_-1

Comment: Maybe I should just order one and measure it! ;)